# GStreamer: Stream vorbis-encoded audio over network

Tags: networking, stream, udp, gstreamer, vorbis

I want to write an app that streams audio and video over the network. As a simple start, I wanted to try out the audio part.

I want to stream vorbis-encoded audio from my microphone over the network. I started with the following pipeline for the receiver:

`gst-launch-0.10 tcpserversrc host=localhost port=3000 ! 
oggdemux ! 
vorbisdec ! 
audioconvert ! 
audio/x-raw-int, endianness="(int)1234", signed="(boolean)true", width="(int)16", depth="(int)16", rate="(int)22000", channels="(int)1" ! 
alsasink`

And for the sender:

`gst-launch-0.10 autoaudiosrc ! 
audio/x-raw-int,rate=22000,channels=1,width=16 ! 
audioconvert ! 
vorbisenc ! 
oggmux ! 
tcpclientsink host=localhost port=3000`

This kind of works, but the audio is snatchy.

Can someone give me a hint how I can vorbis-encode and stream audio from my microphone *smoothly* over the network?

EDIT: I used `audiotestsrc` and made a recording of the output: http://db.tt/oDuQ2O41

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried those commands below (sligthly modified from those in the original post)
and could they solved the "snatchy" sound problem for me

sender:

```
gst-launch-0.10 autoaudiosrc ! \
audio/x-raw-int, endianness="(int)1234", signed="(boolean)true", width="(int)16", depth="(int)16", rate="(int)22000", channels="(int)1" ! \
audioconvert ! \
vorbisenc ! \
oggmux max-delay=50 max-page-delay=50 ! \
tcpclientsink host=localhost port=3000
```

receiver:

```
gst-launch-0.10 tcpserversrc host=localhost port=3000 ! \
oggdemux ! \
vorbisdec ! \
audioconvert ! \
audio/x-raw-int, endianness="(int)1234", signed="(boolean)true", width="(int)16", depth="(int)16", rate="(int)22000", channels="(int)1" ! \
pulsesink
```

Answer (score 0):

change your sender pipeline to -

`gst-launch-0.10 autoaudiosrc ! audio/x-raw-int,rate=22000,channels=1,width=16 ! audioconvert ! vorbisenc ! identity silent=true sync=true  ! oggmux ! tcpclientsink host=localhost port=3000`

This will control the data generation rate to pipeline clock.
Let me know if this works.

Comment: I tried it, but it did not change anything. Audio is still snatchy. I am going to make a recording of the snatches (tomorrow or so), maybe that helps identifying the issue. Thanks anyways!